# ORM to work in tandem with Knex.js for on Angular/Express/Postgres DB

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, orm, knex.js

I started an angular/express project some weeks ago. I found knex.js and was using it for seeding/migrations and then I realized I could use it's query builder to perform the CRUD operations as well. I think my last missing piece is an ORM. I'm looking for a widely used library that can generate the DB tables into JavaScript objects so I don't have to do it from scratch / continuously modify as I build, does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: You will be better off just writing those models and relations that you need by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ORMs, you can use them to create the model classes for application based on the DB tables.

- [Sequelize](https://sequelize.org/)
- [TypeORM](https://typeorm.io/)

Comment: Which parts of DB schema generators of those libraries support?